# Microstation Connect VBA: How to select an element in screen

Tags: vba, microstation

I have a VBA code to copy some elements, but when I try to select any element in the screen, I can't: I need to close my form to do it. I just need to allow Element Selection with my form opened.

I'm trying with `CadInputQueue.SendKeyIn "MDL KEYIN PSELECT CHOOSE ELEMENT"` (I got this by recording a macro).

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just change ShowModal from true to false.